# For $x\in[0,1]$ find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2 x}{e^{n^2 x^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

now this expression gives infinity over infinity so l'hospital rule can be used and the limit is zero which makes sense because the exponential is faster . but my question is what happens when x is zero. we will have infinity multiplied by zero in the numerator and e to the power infinity multiplied by zero in the denominator. so will the limit goes to zero or to infinity ? can we still use l'hospital rule?

Comment: Hint: Use $e^y>\frac{y^2}2$ when $y\geq0.$ This follows from the power series for $e^y.$

Comment: For $x>0$ we have $${1\over x}\lim_{n\to\infty}{n^2x^2\over e^{n^2x^2}}={1\over x}\lim_{y\to \infty }{y\over e^y}=0$$ You can use l'Hospital rule for the last limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x$ is $0$ then $\frac{n^2x}{e^{n^2x^2}}=\frac{0}{e^0}=0$
So each entry in the sequence is $0$, hence the limit is $0$
We don't actually have $\infty\cdot0$ because $n$ isn't $\infty$, when we're taking the limit we're considering what happens when $n$ becomes large, but no matter how large $n$ is, $n^2\cdot0$ is still $0$

Comment: what if x goes to zero but not zero

Comment: Generally looking at $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f_n(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x)$ can be different, so it is important to be aware of what exactly you're considering.

In this particular case though, we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{n^2x}{e^{n^2x^2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}0=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^2x}{e^{n^2x^2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}0=0$